# The Delivered to address is my address not the address in the two filed what do I do

Tags: redirection

The delivered to address is the same as my address when checking the source code of a gmail I sent. The address in the To field is no where else. How do I know who is getting the gmail

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking here. Aren't you the recipient of the email?

Comment: No, Sorry I sent an email to my bf when I check the source of the sent gmail I find my address in the Delivered to field Not his. Bottom Line is Ive suspected for some time he recieves copies of everything I send from my phone and pc Gmail or txt...Ive done Nothing wrong but Need Verification for sure its too much to deal with.

Comment: Having your own address in the "Delivered to:" field is normal for sent messages.  Why not [edit] your question and ask how you can tell whether someone is forwarding your sent messages to another address?

Comment: Depending on the phone and mail program, a copy of a sent message might be delivered to you (the sender), as well as to whomever you sent the message to.  In the source of your message, "Delivered to" is only for your particular copy of the message; and, not a status on who else had received the message.